# In Python how do I tell if file has a utf-8 signature before I start reading

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

I am writing a filter that reads a file (possibly `stdin`) and possibly writes to `stdout`.  If the input file starts with a byte order mark I want the output file to have one, otherwise I don't.  If I open a file with a BOM as `utf-8` then the first character my program reads is the BOM (`\uFEFF`), which I don't want.  If I open a file without a BOM as `utf-8-sig` it reads it properly, but I can't tell whether to open the output as `utf-8` (which will have no signature) or `utf-8-sig`, which will start the file with a signature mark.  So what I want to do is to look at the first character of the file and based on its value decide which encoding to use to open the file.  If it were a disk file I could simply close it and reopen it, but because it could be stdin I can't do that.  I can work around it by having my program check the first character it reads and output it if it is a signature mark, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.  I observe that if I open the file as

```
f = io.open(inFile, encoding="utf-8", buffering=1)
```

and then do `f.buffer.peek(1)` I get back a Unicode object with the first characters of the file.  That seems odd because what I would expect from `peek(`) of the bufferd `iobase` class that has `peek()` would be a Unicode object of length 1.  Now I could look at the first character of what peek returns, and if it is a signature mark read one character and write it to the output, or discard it and then open the output file with `utf-8-sig`, but I don't really like basing a solution on so much observed, rather than documented, behavior.

Any ideas how to do this right?

[I solved this in my case by having the parsing logic ignore the BOM.]

I also find that when I open the output as

```
fOut = io.open(sys.stdout.fileno(), mode="at", encoding="utf-8", closefd=False)
```

I get an extra `<CR>` at the end of each line (`<CR><CR><LF>`) which I don't get if I open an actual file.

I tried opening with mode="ab" which didn't work.  What does seem to work is to add newline="\n":

```
fOut = io.open(sys.stdout.fileno(), mode="at", encoding="utf-8", newline="\n", closefd=False)
```

I think the reason this "works" is because of the same anomaly.  As coded it should be using LF as the terminator.  In fact, if you feed it input with UNIX line terminators it still outputs DOS line terminators.

I am running Python 2.7.13 on Windows 10.

Thanks.

Gary

Comment: have you tried `fOut = io.open(sys.stdout.fileno(), mode="ab",  closefd=False)` ?

Comment: `\uFEFF` is a byte-order marker. A non-utf8 file could start with those two bytes, and a utf8 file isn't required to start with a byte-order marker.

Comment: You could write a wrapper around the open file which checks the first character and saves it to an attribute, but doesn't return. If all you need is iterating over lines, then this wrapper can be a simple iterator which treats the first line specially. If you need stuff like `.seek()`, it could inherit from `io.TextIOWrapper`.

Comment: Do you really need to be guessing the encoding of the file? Can you agree with the sender which you all are using or let the user tell you each time if your program allows them to supply files with encodings of their choice?